# R: cannot read API call - Error in open.connection(con, "rb")

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I can see the contents of the API call in webbrowser, but getting this error with `jsonlite` package: `read_json`.

```
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : connection cannot be opened
Añso: Warning message:
In open.connection(con, "rb") :
  cannot open URL 'https://www.plazavea.com.pe/api/catalog_system/pub/products/search?fq=C:/678/687/&_from=21&_to=41&O=OrderByScoreDESC&': HTTP status was '206 Partial Content'
```

**Code:**:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)



api_request <- "https://www.plazavea.com.pe/api/catalog_system/pub/products/search?fq=C:/678/687/&_from=21&_to=41&O=OrderByScoreDESC&"

product_data <- jsonlite::read_json(api_request)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use httr and then extract `as = 'text'` and pass over to `parse_json()`, or simply specify `as = 'parsed'` in the `content()` call on the response object.

```
library(httr)

api_request <- "https://www.plazavea.com.pe/api/catalog_system/pub/products/search?fq=C:/678/687/&_from=21&_to=41&O=OrderByScoreDESC&"

product_data <- content(httr::GET(api_request), as = 'parsed')
```

Comment: Would you mind, checking this other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69237960/r-cannot-find-discounted-price-from-api-response ty.