# R: cannot find discounted price from API response

Tags: r, json

I'm trying to get all brands, products, prices, price before, price Oh!.

1. I cannot get from where the price Oh is rendered.
2. I wanted the API to return all products at once:

So intead of: `&_from=0&_to=20`, I tried: `&_from=0&_to=540`, but it is not working. I get: `HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'`

Is there a way to get all the info at once?

[image]

**Code:**

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)


x <- httr::GET("https://www.plazavea.com.pe/api/catalog_system/pub/products/search?fq=C:/678/687/&_from=0&_to=20&O=OrderByScoreDESC")



y <- x %>% 
  httr::content(as = "text") %>% 
  jsonlite::parse_json() %>% 
  tibble::tibble() %>% 
  tidyr::unnest_wider(1) %>% 
  #select(productId,productName,items) %>%  # dropping extra stuff for now
  unnest_longer(items) %>% 
  unnest_wider(items) %>% 
  unnest_longer(sellers) %>% 
  unnest_wider(sellers) %>% 
  unnest_wider(commertialOffer)


colnames(y)

w <- y %>%
  select(c(productName, Price, ListPrice, PriceWithoutDiscount))
```

Comment: Was the answer below what you were after?

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot get from where the price Oh is rendered.

There is no JavaScript rendering with xmlhttp requests such as those made by rvest/httr. That requires a browser with its JavaScript engine. For pages like these, where there is templating and the values are retrieved dynamically, you need to ascertain how the value you see on the page are generated. The discounted price is the result of subtracting the specified discount amount from the given price - both of which are provided in the API response. It is just that the structure is horribly nested and it takes a little logic to work out that is what is done (or read through the content provider's JavaScript files).

Given the complexity of the parsed response, you need to study the structure of what is returned and determine the appropriate values and the paths to reach them. Here is a way to retrieve values by providing a list of accessors for indexing into the object using `purrr:pluck`. I would say long-term this is likely fragile due to the use of hardcoded numeric indices in particular.

```
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)

get_discount <- function(item) {
  pluck(item, 1, "sellers", 1, "commertialOffer", "Teasers", 1, "<Effects>k__BackingField", 1, 2, "<Value>k__BackingField") %>%
    as.integer() %>%
    .[1] %>%
    replace_na(0)
}

get_price <- function(item) {
  pluck(item, 1, "sellers", 1, "commertialOffer", "Price")
}

x <- httr::GET("https://www.plazavea.com.pe/api/catalog_system/pub/products/search?fq=C:/678/687/&_from=0&_to=20&O=OrderByScoreDESC")

y <- httr::content(x, as = "parsed") %>%
  tibble::tibble() %>%
  tidyr::unnest_wider(1) %>%
  select(productId, productName, brand, linkText, productTitle, items) %>%
  mutate(
    discount = lapply(items, get_discount) %>% unlist(),
    price = lapply(items, get_price) %>% unlist(),
    discounted_price = ifelse(discount == 0, NA_integer_, price - discount)
  ) %>%
  select(-items)
```

> I wanted the API to return all products at once

For the request itself, you can play around with those params to try and optimize offset and batch size but ultimately the ranges allowable are server side configured. If this a documented API then these maybe described in terms of limits, otherwise, you will need to trial and error optimize/find a proper public and documented API.

Comment: I'd welcome suggested improvements from readers.